# how can i rotate a shape in canvas,html5?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

im tried to rotate a line with this

```
window.onload= function(){
        var canvas=document.getElementById("foo");
        var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.moveTo(250, 50);
        context.lineTo(250, 250);
        context.stroke();
        context.rotate(0.30);

    };
```

what am i doing wrong? i think im missing some steps. can anyone explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
context.rotate(0.30); // <<< set current transformation to rotated
context.moveTo(250, 50);
context.lineTo(250, 250);
context.stroke();
```

Comment: so just the order of things? is this a rule? all the transformations must be done before stroke?

Comment: Naturally, when you call stroke it draws the line immediately and when the rotate function is called the line has already been drawn, thus, it is not going to be affected by the roation, so you do it before.

Answer (score 28):

the rotate() actually rotates the entire coordinate system. Which defaults to 0,0 (Upper left corner of your canvas). You'd need to do something along these lines:

```
context.save(); // saves the coordinate system
context.translate(250,50); // now the position (0,0) is found at (250,50)
context.rotate(0.30); // rotate around the start point of your line
context.moveTo(0,0) // this will actually be (250,50) in relation to the upper left corner
context.lineTo(0,200) // (250,250)
context.stroke();
context.restore(); // restores the coordinate system back to (0,0)
```

Check out this link for a really good explanation of how translate() and rotate() work:
[tutsplus tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/canvas-from-scratch-transformations-and-gradients/)

Steve

Answer (score 0):

```
context.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * 25); //Rotate the canvas by 25 degrees
```

```js
context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * 25); //Rotate the canvas by 25 degrees
context.moveTo(250, 50);
context.lineTo(250, 250);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
context.restore(); // to reset the canvas rotation
```